# CSS Grid: `grid-auto-flow: row` fails to horizontally align children

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a div and form element inside a container set to `display: grid`. Both have a gold dashed border in this image:

[image]

And the CSS rules on the container:

```
const MainAreaContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  align-items: center; // removing this and justify-items only left aligns the child elements
  justify-items: center;

  > * {
    border: 2px dashed gold;
    margin: 15px 20px;
  }
`;
```

I have plenty of width for this to go on one row. Does anyone know why it continues to stack vertically?

Comment: you need `grid-auto-flow: column;` not row. what you are having is row

Comment: Thank you, it works. I guess the specified axis is where the wrapping goes then? 

Edit: It looks like it is not wrapping at small screen widths

Comment: it's not wrong but it's a bit tricky when you don't have an explicit grid defined. Wil try to find an answer explaining this, if not will write a detailed one.

Comment: *It looks like it is not wrapping at small screen widths* --> grid doesn't wrap, if you want a wrap, consider flexbox or define a grid column template with auto-fit/auto-fill